# Suppose that $(X,d)$ is a metric space and we use the distance function. $d_A (x) = \inf{ \{ d(x,y) : y \in A \} } \forall A \subset X $ Prove that $d

Tags: analysis

Suppose that $(X,d)$ is a metric space and we use the distance function.
$d_A (x) = \inf{ \{ d(x,y) : y \in A \} } \forall A \subset X $
Prove that $d_B (x) = d_{\overline{B}} (x)$ for any $B \subset X$

Comment: Closure no doubt.

Comment: Try something. $\ge$ is almost immediate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B \subset \overline{B}$ then $A :=\{d(x,y) \, : \, y \in B \} \subset \{ d(x,y) \, : \, y \in \overline{B}\} := C$

Thus we have that inf $C \leq \text{inf }A$

Then $d_{\overline{B}}(x) \leq d_{B}(x)$.

Suppose that $\alpha = d_{\overline{B}}(x) < d_{B}(x)$. Then we have that $d_{B}(x) = \alpha + \varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$

There exist a sequence in $C$, $\{c_{n} \}$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} c_{n} \to \alpha$

Then for each $n$ there exist $y_{n} \in \overline{B}$ such that $c_{n} = d(x,y_{n})$

As $y_{n} \in \overline{B}$, for all $\delta > 0$ there exist some $z \in B$ such that $z \in B(y_{n},\delta)$

If we take $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{4}$, we have that for all $n$ there exist some $z_{n} \in B$ such that $z_{n} \in B(y_{n},\frac{\varepsilon}{4})$

$\implies d(y_{n},z_{n}) < \frac{\varepsilon}{4}$ for all $n$

Thus we have that (*): $d(x,z_{n}) \leq d(x,y_{n}) + d(y_{n},z_{n}) < d(x,y_{n}) + \frac{\varepsilon}{4} = c_{n} + \frac{\varepsilon}{4}$

And we have that $c_{n} \to \alpha$, then there exist some $N$ such that if $n>N \implies |c_{n} - \alpha| < \frac{\varepsilon}{4} $

Then $c_{n} < \alpha + \frac{\varepsilon}{4}$ for all $n > N$

Then in (*): $d(x,z_{n}) < c_{n} + \frac{\varepsilon}{4} < \alpha + \frac{\varepsilon}{4} + \frac{\varepsilon}{4} = \alpha + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for all $n > N$

But $z_{n} \in B \implies d(x,z_{n}) \in A \implies \alpha + \varepsilon = \text{inf }A \leq d(z_{n},x) < \alpha + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$

This is a contradiction.

Then we have that $d_{B}(x) = d_{\overline{B}}(x)$